# Debian PHP server: How do you keep it in date?

Tags: php, debian

According to the PHP documentation on [unsupported branches](https://www.php.net/eol.php)

> using [unsupported branches of PHP] may expose you to security vulnerabilities and bugs that have been fixed in more recent versions of PHP.

Debian 11, the current stable release, comes with PHP 7.4. which according to the PHP documentation on [supported versions](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php) ceased being actively supported 6 months ago and will only be supported for security for another 5 months. I assume this means that in 5 months time, which seems like a short time in the life of a production web server, PHP 7.4 will be considered as unsupported by the official PHP organization.

What should I do in order to set up a Debian server for a secure production PHP website?

My current best idea is to set up Apache on Debian 11 and import an 'unofficial' repository from Ondřej Surý who seems to have a good reputation for producing reliable PHP packages. Then I should be able to install PHP 8 from his repository.

Another idea would be to use PHP 7.4 with Debian 11 now and upgrade to Debian 12 assuming it ships with PHP 8. That would presumably be the safest approach theoretically but in practice sounds like a lot of admin with scope for a lot of problems.

I have seen quite a lot of advice which strongly urges users not to install software from repositories that do not ship with the distro. This [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) from Debian is an example.

Are there more sensible alternatives? If so what are they? If not which of my ideas should I pursue?

Comment: We had the same debate and ended up going with Ubuntu. Had we stuck with Debian we would have stayed with 7.4. Which way are you leaning?

Comment: I had thought the situation would probably be the same with Ubuntu but will look into that. I am attracted by Debian because other distros are based on it so I think why not go for the upstream one. I was leaning towards Debian 11 plus PHP 8 from Ondřej Surý's repository but am still undecided. I also want to find out how much this applies to other packages I might need to use.

Comment: note that Debian is committed to provide security support for packages in (still supported) Debian releases, even if an upstream's project has stopped doing so. so if the PHP developers no longer support PHP-7.4, but Debian 11 shipped with PHP-7.4 you will still get security support for PHP7.4 until the EOL of Debian11 (whenever that is). Obviously you must have the security repositories enabled.